# How do different Astika schools prove re-incarnation according to this verse of Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, advaita, shad-darshana, samkhya

Different schools - Shatdarshanas in Indian philosophy tackle the phenomenon of reincarnation differently. While there are sufficient yogic practices to experience past lives when on the path of self-inquiry and jnana, I want to know how such are tackled via arguments and logic techniques.

To the best of my knowledge, in Advaita Vedanta, the enlightenment (jivanmukta/avadhuta) stage comes before and this is considered liberation. But the person will keep birthing till the attachment to the human body ceases (this attachment remains due to prarabdha karma). Correct me if I'm wrong here. The atman is eternal and he never dies, nor he ever takes birth.

How do these schools explain this particular verse from the Bhagavad Gita?

> BG 6.41-42: The unsuccessful yogis, upon death, go to the abodes of
> the virtuous. After dwelling there for many ages, they are again
> reborn in the earth plane, into a family of pious and prosperous
> people. Else, if they had developed dispassion due to long practice of
> Yog, they are born into a family endowed with divine wisdom. Such a
> birth is very difficult to attain in this world.

Src: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6/verse/41-42

Comment: Correct. Its the Subtle Body that does the travelling. Atman as such doesnt come and go anywhere